# Возможно ли задавать свойстсва других классов в анимации другого?(@keyframes)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

К примеру, существует следующая конструкция:

```
.paragraph_main
{
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-top: 00px;
    color: gray;
}
    .header_main
{
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    animation: fire 1s;
}
@keyframes fire

{   

    50%
    {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #FFF, 0 0 1px #FFF, 0 0 5px #FFF, 0 0 20px #5e71a8, 0 0 30px #5e71a8, 0 0 40px #5e71a8, 0 0 55px #5e71a8, 0 0 75px #5e71a8;
    }
    
    100%
    {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #FFF, 0 0 1px #FFF, 0 0 5px #FFF, 0 0 20px #445790, 0 0 30px #445790, 0 0 40px #445790, 0 0 55px #445790, 0 0 75px #445790;
    }
}
```

Есть ли способ изменить свойства объекта классa .paragraph_main в анимации fire?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Нет, нельзя изменять свойства одного класса внутри анимации другого класса. Вы можете сделать это только через JavaScript, изменяя стили динамически. Вы можете добавить или удалить класс в зависимости от состояния анимации, и определить свойства этого класса.

Comment: А как изменять стили динамически? А какие есть состояние анимации и как их отлавливать? А как удалять и добавлять классы? Если вы считаете что это "ответ", тогда огорчу вас, это максимум комментарий.